# C++ Binary Search Issue with Array Length

Tags: c++, arrays, string, visual-studio, binary-search

The code below for some reason when you enter "b" or anything(consider is already sorted) does not give output "GOTCHA\n" however if I use vector it works fine! it seems if you debug it the string size x->length()-1; does not give the length of the array instead gives 0 as the max length what's the solution?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string x[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
string s;
cin >> s;
int max = x->size()-1;
int min = 0;
int middle = (max + min) / 2;
while (min <= max) //BinarySearch Begins
{
    middle = (max + min) / 2;
    if (s == x[middle]) //if found display message
    {
        cout << "GOTCHA\n";
        break;
    }
    else if (s > x[middle])//if actual string is after first guess increase
        min = middle + 1;
    else max = middle - 1; //else decrease
 }
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: x->length() is not correct. Use sizeof(x)

Comment: use `std::vector` instead of raw array, at least it will not let you do such mistakes `x->size()` and programming by guessing does not work

Comment: vector does work but why String doesn't?

Comment: `std::vector` instead of array not instead of `std::string`

Comment: @JotunMichael If the issue is determining how many items there are in an array, why do you need to post an entire binary search program?  Just write a simple 2 line main() program where you declare an array and attempt to output the number of elements.  A [mcve] next time, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this

```
int max = sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]) - 1;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: glad that it helped you

Answer (score 0):

In the below code 'x' is a C style array, you should use sizeof(x) in order to return it's size. x->length() or x->size() are not correct.

```
   int max = x->size()-1;
```